# how to add user define variable with some predefine integer in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add user define number with some predefine integer. But I am getting the wrong output.

I have a user define the variable 'qdt'. suppose the value of qdt is '5000.00'.
I want to 2000 in qdt. I need output  7000.00 but I am getting '5000.002000'.

where I am doing wrong with the function? please help.

thank You.

```
    <script>
            function totalise() {    
            var qtd   = document.getElementById('qt').value;
            var myCheck1 = document.getElementById('myCheck1');
            var myCheck2 = document.getElementById('myCheck2');
            if (myCheck1.checked == true){
            var qtd   = document.getElementById('qt').value;

            qtd = qtd + 2000;

            } else {
                    if (myCheck2.checked == true){
                         var qtd   = document.getElementById('qt').value;

                           qtd = qtd + 500;

                    }else{
                         var qtd   = document.getElementById('qt').value;
                    }
                    var qtd   = document.getElementById('qt').value;
            }
            document.getElementById('result').value = qtd ;
            }
    </script>
```

Comment: Its not a number type, so its just concatenating it, `'5000.00'+'2000'`

Comment: You can use parseInt to parse a string to a number. To be on the safe side of things, always pass 10 as the second argument to parse in base 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need convert to number before add

```
var qtd   = document.getElementById('qt').value;

qtd = parseFloat(qtd) + 500;
```